# Android Studio 3.1.3 reconoce como "null mis imagenes"

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Cuando intento hacer referencia a una imagen desde el código de una actividad recibo el problema:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.deybin.figuremapsearching/com.example.deybin.figuremapsearching.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object
>   reference

Este es el problema principal:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object
>   reference

agradecería mucho cualquier respuesta

---

Tengo my Image View, y también lo tengo enlazado a mi xml.

Sospecho que mi problema es de:
Compatibilidad o quizá dependa del lugar en el código de donde los haya referido.

No incluiré el código que me solicitas porque consider no tiene objeto, muchas gracias

Comment: No son las imagenes el problema agrega tu Activity y tu layout que carga esta activity.

Comment: Tienes que agregar tu código, viendo eso se te puede dar cierta ayuda pero no asegurar que lo que te digamos sea la solución.

Comment: @Deybi, el archivo que cargas mediante setContentView debe tener el ImageView que obtienes mediante findViewById() , te sugiero aportar estos detalles, el error es debido a que no existe la referencia o no la estas obteniendo correctamente.Te sugiero agregar la información que comento.

Answer (score 1):

En realidad el problema no son las imágenes, es la vista la cual no existe, al obtener la referencia de la vista, en este caso el `ImageView`, esta no existe por lo tanto no puedes cargar las imágenes usando `setImageResource()`:

```
ImageView.setImageResource(int)
```

Puedes no estar obteniendo la referencia del `ImageView` mediante `findViewById()` o el layout donde buscas la referencia no existe el `ImageView`.

Agrega como obtienes la referencia y tu layout para ampliar la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa el layout que carga el activity que sea el correcto, ya que el error que te muestra

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object
>   reference

Te indica que el objeto es nulo, con lo que no puedes operar con el.

Como alternativa, que veo que has acabo de upgradear android studio

`File\Invalidate Caches and Restart` y vuelve a compilar

Answer (score 0):

ImageView probelma;

@Oberride
Oncreate (.......{
{
Problema = (ImageView) findViewbyId (R.id.iVisormagen);
}

Public void unaFuncion (View view){
   While (condicion){
      If (condicion){}
      else {
          switch (valor){
             Case(1):{
                    Probelma.setImageResource (R.drawable.laimagen);
                    //A demás he probado el setImageDrawable
                    // Obteniendo la misma exceptcion.

```
               // en mi carpeta( res/drawables) tengo mi png "laimagen".
```

Este es el contexto en el que he recibido el problema.

Muchas gracias a todos quienes han respondido.
Lamento no haber incluido el código desde un principio. He agregado el esquema